# extension for DbSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, entity-framework

What is extension for DbSet? I want to add method 'FindTheLatest'. this is my code:
this is my code

```
    public static List FindTheLatest(this DbSet<Review> reviews, int nums)
    {
        return reviews.OrderByDescending(r => r.Created).Take(nums).ToList();
    }
```

But it doesn't work. What i must to do?

this is my extension class:

```
public static class RestaurantReviewsExtenstion
{
    public static IEnumerable<Review> FindTheLatest(this IQueryable<Review> reviews, int nums)
    {
        return reviews.OrderByDescending(r => r.Created).Take(nums).ToList();
    }

    public static Review FindById(this System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Review> reviews, int id)
    {
        return reviews.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ReviewId == id);
        //return reviews.Find(item => item.Id == id);
    }

    public static Review FindTheBest(this List<Review> list)
    {
        return list.OrderByDescending(o => o.Rating).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

this is my DBContex Class:

```
public class OdeToFoodDb: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
            .HasMany(resturant => resturant.Reviews)
            .WithRequired(review => review.Resturant);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

this is where i get error:

```
    OdeToFoodDb _db = new OdeToFoodDb();
    public PartialViewResult LatestReview()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
        //this is where i get error
        var review = _db.Reviews.FindTheLatest(1);
        //************************************
        return PartialView("_Review", review);
    }
```

Sorry about poor information.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is *never* a good enough description of what's wrong.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Or unexpected results?

Comment: I am sorry,
I am new to this forum, and my English is poor and bad :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well for one thing, `List` is a generic type. For another `DbSet` isn't a set of any *specific* type - you probably want `DbSet<T>` for some appropriate `T`. Perhaps you mean:

```
public static List<Review> FindTheLatest(this DbSet<Review> reviews, int nums)
{
    return reviews.OrderByDescending(r => r.Created).Take(nums).ToList();
}
```

Or:

```
public static List<Review> FindTheLatest(this DbSet reviews, int nums)
{
    return reviews.Cast<Review>()
                  .OrderByDescending(r => r.Created)
                  .Take(nums)
                  .ToList();
}
```

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi: Well without any more information, I can't see how I could *possibly* help any more. You're the one asking for help - it's up to you to provide all the relevant information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: In my video training used this code:
        public static IEnumerable<Review> FindTheLatest(this IQueryable<Review> reviews, int nums)
        {
            return reviews.OrderByDescending(r => r.Created).Take(nums).ToList();
        }
but, it also didn't works for me :(.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi why are you calling `ToList()` if you are returning `IEnumerable`? What `didn't works for me` means? Is it too green, or too hot for you?

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi: You've now said **three times** that it doesn't work, but despite being asked several times for more information, you haven't said what's not working. Do you not understand that we can't help you until you tell us *how* it's not working?

Comment: Im sorry: i get following error:

'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<OdeToFood.Models.Review>' does not contain a definition for 'FindTheLatest' and no extension method 'FindTheLatest' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<OdeToFood.Models.Review>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Actually I have Odetofood that is derived from DBcontext class. Reveiw is a DbSet in this DBContext class

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet it works fine. I added your code to my extension class. But i forgot to add appropriate namespace to the page. Thank you.

Comment: @jonskeet I love this approach, however how would you go about mocking ? What I'm currently doing is that when a part I'm testing calls that extension method, I populate the mocked DbSet with test data and rely on the fact that I have tested the extension method and know what it's supposed to return. It somehow breaks test isolation and I wonder if it is acceptable or too much sketchy. I would really like to avoid building repositories on top of EF, and beside this testing "issue" I find that extension methods would really shine here.

Comment: It should be ok, since MS recommends doing the same for other querying scenarios (replacing the IQueryable provider of the dbset, with the one of a dummy list treated as an iqueryable). But I'd like to confirm that with an other point of view.

Comment: @red2nb: I'm afraid I have no experience of using EF in anger. Personally my ideal situation is an in-memory version of the real database - something that can be brought up and torn down in milliseconds, but which still works exactly like the more persistent version. Unfortunately as far as I'm aware, most major database don't support that scenario as well as I'd like :(

Comment: @jonskeet you should have a look on that : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx#queryTest it seems to me that EF allows you to set up precisely what you describe!  :)

Comment: As per my question, no worries at all, I think I'll continue that way

Comment: @red2nb: No, that's not what I described - because that's basically using LINQ to Objects as the in-memory storage. There are *many* situations where that won't behave the same way as a database query. I'm talking about something which uses the real database engine, in a way that makes it quick to set up and tear down.

Comment: @JonSkeet how can i do it with IQueryable<T> and Func(for use it with any property of entity) instead of List<Review>  ???

Comment: @AminM: You shouldn't expect a `Func<...>` to work with `IQueryable<T>` without fetching the data locally. You should be using `Expression<Func<...>>`. Beyond that, it's not really clear what you're asking. You're probably better off asking a new question.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry i want to make this extension method work with all entity not specific entity, in your answer you use r => r.Created but what if my entity have another property name???

Comment: @AminM: As I suggested before, you should ask a new question. You have different requirements than those of this question.

Answer (score 3):

you can implement extension method using Generic to accept any type:

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FindTheLast<T,TResult>(this IQueryable<T> t, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression, int nums) where T : class 
    {
      return t.OrderByDescending(expression).Take(nums);
    }
}
```

and use it :

```
dbContext.Entity.FindTheLast(x => x.Property,2);
```