# Create pre filter layer in DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I want to protect my entities using a Field called Deleted to don't allow client really delete any entity. If he tries delete, the only thing is that `entity.Deleted = true;`

The problem is that everywhere I don't want to include deleted Entities I'll need to use

`db.Entities.Where(e => e.Deleted == false).WhateverMethod();`

I know I can use a method like this inside my Controller

```
private IQueryable<Entity> GetNotDeletedEntity() {
        return db.Entities.Where(e => e.Deleted == false);
}
```

And change every `db.Entities.WhateverMethod()` for `GetNotDeletedEntity().WhateverMethod()`, but I seems weird for me.

One note is that `GetNotDeletedEntity()` returns IQueryable, and `db.Entities` returns DbSet. This incongruency may be a problem in the future.

I think there's a way to extend DbSet to work like this

`db.Entities // include all entities`

`db.NotDeletedEntities // include only entities e.Deleted == false`

Any advice about how to DRY `.Where(e => e.Deleted == false)` would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this guy was trying to accomplish something very similar. Take a look at Jon Skeet's explanation here: [extension for DbSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518192/extension-for-dbset)